# How I can start and stop my instance for periods in AWS Instance Scheduler

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to start my instance in a region every day at 6 am and stop at 9 pm. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using two ways,

- Lambda function
- AWS Instance Scheduler

**Lambda function**

Note: This example setup is a simple solution. For a more robust solution, use the AWS Instance Scheduler.

**For this setup, do the following:**

> 1. Create a custom AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) policy and execution role for your Lambda function.
> 2. Create Lambda functions that stop and start your EC2 instances.
> 3. Create CloudWatch Events rules that trigger your function on a schedule. For example, you could create a rule to stop your EC2
>      instances at night, and another to start them again in the morning.

For more details follow

[start-stop-lambda-ec2](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/)

**AWS instance Scheduler:**

> You can use the AWS Instance Scheduler and an automated AWS
>   CloudFormation template to stop and start your instances based on a
>   schedule.

[stop-start-instance-scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-start-instance-scheduler/)

Comment: Does any of these solutions work for free??

Comment: free tier of lambda can work

Comment: So even though I am using paid EC2 Instance I can use the free tier of lambda? It's just starting the script at 9 am and stopping at 4 pm during the week days.

Comment: yes, lambda is a separate service that comes with its own free tier limit

Comment: You may want to configure your server with an Elastic IP since the stop will release the non-elastic one. You may get a different public IPv4 after a start all right but this is an inconvenience. Also, in case of multiple network interfaces defined on your server, no public IP gets assigned effectively rendering your server disconnected from the internet. Have a look at the details on when the non-elastic IP gets released: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console#concepts-public-addresses